# Adding another Gmail account to my current Gmail mail box

Tags: gmail

Is there any way to add another Gmail account to an existing Gmail mailbox?

For example, my current email address is "sample@gmail.com", and I have another Gmail account under "newSample@gmail.com".

I want "newSample@gmail.com" to act exactly like "sample@gmail.com". Is it possible?

Actually I have used my current email address for years but I don`t like it. Is it possible for me to change only the email address (my domain name) of my mailbox?

Comment: you want mails to newSample@gmail.com to be forwarded to sample@gmail.com ? or do you want all the emails in sample@gmail.com in newSample.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not change your Gmail address. You will have to create a new email address, copy all your account data (old mails, contacts, labels, etc.) to your new account and forward any incoming mail to your old account into your new account.

For migration you could use: [Gmail Backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/)  and follow the [FAQ on migration](http://www.gmail-backup.com/faq#n1470).

Additionally you should check out [this Google Help article](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=58582) for migration of services associated with your account you might not have thought about.